# Determine the mean volume $\mu$ which will maximize the expected profit

Tags: probability, self-study

A manufacturer sells a bottle of mineral water at a fixed price of $10$. If the volume of water in the bottle is less than $800 ml$ then he is unable to sell it and it represents a total loss. The filled bottles have a normally distributed volume with mean $\mu\ ml$ and standard deviation $100\ ml$. The cost of filling per bottle is $c$, where $c = 0.002\mu + 1$. Determine the mean volume $\mu$ which will maximize the expected profit of the manufacturer.

What I tried:

We have to find $\mu$ such that $10 - c = 9 - 0.002\mu$ is maximum i.e we have to minimize $\mu$.

Then, let $V$ be volume, $\mathbb P(V \ge 800) = 1 - \mathbb P(V\le800)+\mathbb P(V = 800)$. But from here I don't know how to move forward. Any hints?

Comment: You need to write P(V<800) in terms of a normal cdf (perhaps the standard normal) and then write the profit as an expression in $\mu$. Then (for example) standard calculus methods could be applied to find turning points in the profit function. Alternatively, the maximum could be found by more direct means (such as evaluating the profit directly at a sequence of values).

Comment: But I am unable to build a relationship between profit function and the probability of V.

Comment: profit = saleprice $-$ cost. Write *expected* saleprice in terms of P(V<800). Cost is given in your question. Hence obtain expected profit

Comment: Oh, I think you mean *expected cost* because sale-price is fixed. Cool.

Comment: No. Expected cost=cost, because it has no random variation, while sale price is NOT fixed. Sale price is 10 *if V is at least 800 ml*. and is 0 if it isn't ... so sale price is random,